# How to target just the table row clicked on for angularJS ng-show and ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a table in a angularJS app. What I'm trying to do is add a toggle function to show/hide a table data section. The function works, but it toggles every row on the table. I need it to only toggle the row that was click on: Here is an example screencast: http://screencast.com/t/U5XXU7RN3gm

html

```
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-ng-repeat="program in listPrograms | orderBy:predicatemodal:reverse | filter: searchPrograms" isdisabled-program ng-click="setSelected(this)" ng-class="selected">
<td>
    <div popover-placement="right" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover="{{program.programName}}">{{program.programName | characters:20}}</div>
</td>
<td>{{program.waDisplayName == null ? "N/A" :program.waDisplayName | characters:20}}</td>
<td>{{program.startDate}}</td>
<td>{{program.deadline}}</td>
<td >{{program.status}}</td>
<td>
    <div data-ng-hide="showButtons" class="showDate">{{program.updatedDate}}</div>
    <div data-ng-show="showButtons" class="showButtons">
        <a data-ng-click=""><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>edit</a>
        <a data-ng-click=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>details</a>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="program-arrows" data-ng-click="toggleArrows($index)">toggle arrows<span></span>
</td>
</tr>
```

javascript

```
$scope.toggleArrows = function (index) {
        $scope.showButtons = !$scope.showButtons;

    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying "global" `showButtons` property. Try to come up with a property for every button:

```
<div data-ng-hide="program.showButtons" class="showDate">{{program.updatedDate}}</div>
<div data-ng-show="program.showButtons" class="showButtons">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

```js
$scope.toggleArrows = function (index) {
    var program = $scope.listPrograms[index];
    program.showButtons = !program.showButtons;
}
```

---

A better solution would be to add this method to program's prototype, assuming that there is one:

```
Program.prototype.toggleArrows = function () {
    this.showButtons = !this.showButtons;
}
```

```html
<td class="program-arrows" data-ng-click="program.toggleArrows()">toggle arrows<span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `showButtons` variable is a primitive. In your code you just change the `$scope.showButtons` which is just inside of your main `scope`. But in your `ng-repeat` are child scopes, which every contains its own variable `showButtons`.
The most elegant decision is just to change `showButtons` value in context of current child `scope`. So you just change your `ng-click` function like this:

```
<td class="program-arrows" data-ng-click="showButtons = !showButtons">toggle arrows<span></span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick also:

```
$scope.toggleArrows = function (index) {
       this.showButtons = !this.showButtons;
    };
```